# Include files depending on the versions defined in CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a C++11 project and would to have the program to support different versions. 
In the CMakeLists.txt, i have:

```
 set(ProjectName_VERSION_MAJOR 1) 
 set(ProjectName_VERSION_MINOR 0)
 set(ProjectName_VERSION_PATCH 0)
```

which is link according to the [cmake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) to a .h.in file.
I have access to actual versions as macro and different folders with different versions: i.e. v100, v110 ... and in the main.cpp, i have

```
#include "v100/fileName.h"
```

Is there a way to automatically change the "v100" to something like "v110", by just changing the parameters in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: What are you using for version control?

Comment: In CMake you can call scripts so you can do it a python script which do it or you can code with shell commands in CMake with a succession of add_custom_command() like `sed`

Comment: Bernhard, Gitlab